# Issue with using Visual Studio Online to deploy web app

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I need to implement Continuous Integration/Deployment with a .NET 4.5 Web App.
My build definition has 3 steps:

1. Visual Studio Build
2. Visual Studio Test
3. Azure Web App Deployment

The build and test steps work fine. All tests pass. But it throws an error during the deployment step.

Here are my build step settings:
[image: Build settings]

The MSBuild Arguments value is:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.stagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip"
```

Here are my deployment step settings:

[image: Deployment settings]

And here are my build results:

[image: Build Results]

And here is the error message.

[image: Error message]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with **PackageLocation** value given in MSBuild.

Try changing the MSBuild arguments as below:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.stagingDirectory)($ProjectName).cspkg"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a blank space in the Web Deploy Package path, remove it.
[image]